# Why didn't they use a portkey to go from America to Europe?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In the beginning of the film, they need to transport Grindelwald to Europe.
Since not even Voldemort can teleport from the U.K. to continental Europe, it can’t be that way.

So why do they not just use a portkey instead?

Comment: I would imagine the simple answer would be a portkey was not secure enough.  Perhaps they feared Grindelwald or his followers would curse a portkey to transport him somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps the authorities intended something bad to happen to Grindelwald during the carriage trip.  They may have wanted to break his stoicism or to make him disappear permanently.

Comment: US portkeys run at 110V and European ones run at 230V, so they’re not compatible.

Comment: "It hertz so bad, man" --- Probably someone who used a US portkey without a converter @MikeScott

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely speculative, as we have no hard evidence, but transporting the prisoner the slow way, instead of using a portkey would minimise the following risks:

- **How secure are portkeys?** We don't know for sure, but there is a possibility that one of his followers could re-key the portkey to teleport somewhere else. There is no control the moment a person touches the portkey. Unless it's been timed. But even then, it is instantaneous.
- **Fear of Ambush** The party could easily have been ambushed the moment they appeared at target location of the portkey. This would leave them wildly vulnerable.

Comment: I would add that there doesn't seem to be any way of knowing where a Portkey will take you if you didn't create it.  In *Goblet of Fire*, none of the contest organizers (accomplished witches and wizards all) realize that the Goblet is even a Portkey to begin with.

Comment: Agreed. That is why I mentioned point 1. If someone were to re-witch the portkey, the users would have no clue where it takes them.

Comment: i think your points are unconvincing. as we see after arthur weasley is attacked by nagini (or after the battle at the ministry), portkeys can be created quickly, without any chance for grindelwalds followers to intervene, and we see that portkeys can lead to protected locations (like grimauld place no. 12, then under the fidelius-charm, or the headmasters office in hogwarts) - so a portkey is an option, just create it immediately before use and target some prearranged secure location. what i don't know is if a portkey would work over such distances.